# JSON Web Encryption (JWE): should one verify the alg and enc similarly to JWS alg whitelisting?

Tags: encryption, jwt, oauth2

Use of JWS may suffer from flaws when relying on the `"alg"` attribute as described here: [Critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token libraries](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/).

The advice is to verify that the signing JWS algorithm is in a list of accepted algorithms. Practically, most JWS libraries have added am `"alg"` whitelist parameter:

```
verify(string token, string algorithm, string verificationKey)
```

They haven't, however, added such a parameter for JWE decryption.

When proceeding with JWE decryption, should I verify after successful decryption that the `"alg"` and `"enc"` are in a whitelist of acceptable values? In other words, does JWE decryption suffers the same problems than JWS signature verification?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

From [JWT BCP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bcp-06#section-3.1):

> Libraries MUST enable the caller to specify a supported set of
> algorithms and MUST NOT use any other algorithms when performing
> cryptographic operations.  The library MUST ensure that the "alg" or
> "enc" header specifies the same algorithm that is used for the
> cryptographic operation.  Moreover, each key MUST be used with exactly
> one algorithm, and this MUST be checked when the cryptographic
> operation is performed.

Comment: Thnaks, but I'd like to understand what are the security risks: downgrade attack? Or worse like for the JWS ones?

Comment: Also it says the library must rely on the `alg` and `enc` parameters, but what if the JWE is encrypted using a different pair of `alg` / `enc`? In JWS one shall no rely on these fields

Comment: Usoing a library that does not support specifying alg/enc for JWE decryption, I see no other way than checking it after decryption, which contradicts this specification. Are they some specific risks in doing that (side-channel attacks...)?

Comment: Seems like a recipe for DoS. Just extract the alg and enc headers and check them before calling decrypt (look at the code for your library's decryt function to figure out how).